# How can i accept failure alerts when any one of the Processors report errors?

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

UPDATE:
When start The Processor Group,and left Nifi Web,i want to accept failure reminder in order to return Nifi UI web updating The Processor Group.

I try one Processor connect `Putemail` Processor,but only this Processor notification.
Maybe i can connect 10000000 Processor with `Putemail` Processor.Too Stupid!!!!
[image]
**How can i accept failure alerts when any one of the Processors report errors ? TIA**

Comment: what do you mean by "`accept` any processor failure" ?

Comment: @daggett Sorry,i want to get alerts which are triggerd by `any one of processors` in order to return UI web,after i left.

Comment: you should spend more time in articulating your question better, it is very hard to make sense of your question?

Comment: @Up_One sorry,u are right...i have updated

Answer (score 0):

**How can i accept failure alerts when any one of the Processors report errors ? TIA**

When you say - **accept failure alerts** - does this mean check the alert and allow the flow to continue ?

If so ! you should build this logic inside a **route** processor.

Still i am guessing here, your question requires Urgent refactoring(maybe is language limitation)

Comment: Sorry...my aim is getting alerts for updating processor,after i left Nifi UI.